# Parse Relationship Versus ObjectId

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I have a User and a Topic class  Each topic is associated with a user.  Is there a meaningful difference between setting a relationship in Topic to User versus simply saving the user's objectId as a String in Topic?  Both work, but I'm wondering if there are any performance or other benefits to the relationship approach.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a Pointer in this case. Because if you use this approach there is no need on querying again for the user like you will need to do if you save only the objectId string. Even if you are using Cloud-Code or not, to achieve a reliable application you should work with Pointers, thats how it was designed.

When I work with relationships in parse I usually follow this:

- One-to-One = Pointer
- One-to-Many = Pointer
- Many-to-Many = Relation

So, in your example, when you save the Topic PFObject make sure you set the PFUser object to it. So if you want to save the current user as the owner of a topic you could do the following:

```
newTopic["owner"] = PFUser.currentUser()
newTopic.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
....
```

This will set a pointer to the user that is saved in parse. So you will have access to the whole PFUser object when retrieving the Topic.

Comment: My question is whether this is a distinction without a difference.  if I save the user's objectId, I can retrieve the user just as easily using that.  I guess it's a bit more code in iOS to do so, but not in cloud code (where you just use "get").

Comment: @pickwick just made some updates on the question to clarify some details

Answer (score 0):

Well the difference is about the type of a relationship you want to have between your data. If you store a user objetcId as string, you are simply creating a one-to-one relationship between a User and a Topic (this is very similar to using a Pointer)

If you use a Relation, then you are technically forming a one-to-many relationship where a Topic can have many associated users. Relation is designed to be scalable and it is suitable (performance wise) for much larger datasets.